# Correct Regex for Passing Time Zone in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, spring-boot

I am currently using a regex to interprete the below format.

File Name : File_[TimeStamp:yyyyMMdd_HHmm].csv and regex for interpreting the format is : "\[TimeStamp(:[^\[\]]+)?\]" .
it will return a String with timestamp value : File_20230120_1716.csv

The sample code which support interpreting the timestamp format in the filename:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Test {
    private static final String DEFAULT_FORMAT= "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
    private static final String TIMESTAMP_REGEX = "\\[TimeStamp(:[^\\[\\]]+)?\\]";
    public  static String processFileName(String value, String regex ) {
        LocalDateTime dateTime=LocalDateTime.now();
        Matcher matcher=Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(value);
        while(matcher.find()) {
            DateTimeFormatter dtf=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DEFAULT_FORMAT);
            if(matcher.group(1)!=null) {
                dtf=DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(matcher.group(1).replaceFirst(":", ""));
            }
            value=value.replace(matcher.group(0), dtf.format(dateTime));
        }
        return value;
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        String str=processFileName("File_[TimeStamp:yyyyMMdd_HHmm].csv", TIMESTAMP_REGEX);
        System.out.println(str);
       }
}
```

Output: File_20230120_1716.csv
Currently I can use File_[TimeStamp:yyyyMMdd_HHmm].csv or File_[TimeStamp].csv formats to interprete with above regex.

But I wanted to modify the above "\[TimeStamp(:[^\[\]]+)?\]" sothat it can interpret ZonId also in this format : File_[TimeStam|Asia\Tokyo:yyyyMMdd_HHmm].csv.
Based upon ZoneId from the input I will modify the LocalDateTime value.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the timestamp and file extension is always going to be the same amount of characters, so you don't need a character class.

So, given `File_[TimeStamp:yyyyMMdd_HHmm].csv`.

The pattern `\[TimeStamp(:[^\[\]]+)?\]` can be reduced to the following.

```
\[TimeStamp(.{14}).{5}
```

Now, you're saying that you'd like to be able to match not only the text "TimeStamp", but also other values.

You can place the text `TimeStamp` within a non-capturing group, and use the `|` specifier, to delimit a set of possible values.

```
\[(?:TimeStamp|Asia/Tokyo)(.{14}).{5}
```

So now, both of the following values will match.

```
File_[TimeStamp:yyyyMMdd_HHmm].csv
File_[Asia/Tokyo:yyyyMMdd_HHmm].csv
```

Furthermore, you're saying that you want it to match a ZoneId which is provided at runtime.

You can use the `String.format` for this, using the `%s` specifier to interpolate a `String` value into a `String`.

Consider the following.
I've excluded the ZoneId value, as I'm not sure what your variable name will be.

```java
String regex = "\\[(?:TimeStamp|%s)(.{14}).{5}";
String zoneId = Pattern.quote(/* zoneId */);
regex = regex.formatted(zoneId);
```

If I used `America/Phoenix` as a ZoneId value, and we output the value of `regex`, we'll get the following.

```
\[(?:TimeStamp|\QAmerica/Phoenix\E)(.{14}).{5}
```

In conclusion, you can re-factor you code, as follows.

```java
private static final String DEFAULT_FORMAT = "yyyyMMddHHmmss";
private static final String TIMESTAMP_REGEX = "\\[TimeStamp(.{14}).{5}";

public static String processFileName(String value, String regex) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(value);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(DEFAULT_FORMAT);
        if (matcher.group(1) != null)
            dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(matcher.group(1).substring(1));
        value = value.replace(matcher.group(0), dtf.format(dateTime));
    }
    return value;
}
```

Output

```
File_20230521_1711
```